# CSS select next match

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Having a layout such as this:

```
<div class="a">
    <div>
        <div class="b">
            <div class="b">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it at all possible to style only the first div class b without necessarily defining the entire path to b ?

```
.a .b {
    border: 1px solid green;
} // Will style also the second b
.a > div > .b {
    border: 1px solid red;
} // Path too strictly defined
```

Off course my structure **is not this simple**, and the content inside the div class b can be anything, so I don't want to strictly define the styles from a down to b and all other elements.

There should be a css selector which says **"first next match"**.

Comment: What do you mean by "next match"? Do you want the first match, or the "next" match, whatever that is?

Answer (score 2):

> There should be a css selector which says **"first next match"**.

Well, there isn't. You're going to have to specify the exact structure for which to match your element, which you already have done with `.a > div > .b`. If there are any inner elements whose styles you need to override, you need to add separate rules for those elements.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of knew this, I just wanted to put it out there really. If one is developing modules and using modular/reusable code, this kind of become essential.

Answer (score 1):

The best way in order to maintain your code with a more complex structure would be to add another class :

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
    <div>
        <div class="b parent">
            <div class="b">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a .b {
    border: 1px solid green;
} 
.a .b.parent {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

**SCSS**

```
.a {
    .b {
        border: 1px solid green;

        &.parent {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. (That is SCSS by the way, not Sass.)

Comment: My bad, I use SASS denomination for both.

Comment: Since we are in on the topic, SCSS vs LESSCSS, what is your thoughts?

Comment: Also, this answer won't do, since this just plainly goes around the problem. I might still have b parent nested within b parent higher up.

Comment: @MoJS There's no CSS selector to exactly do what you want. You must differentiate `b.parent` from `b.child`, and I'm pretty sure you can. Sure, you can use JS instead, but it looks like using a tank for an ant. About LESCC vs SASS/SCSS, SASS is a bit better on several points, like media-queries or `@extend`, but it's mostly feeling-based.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest CSS:

```
.a > div > div {
    border: 1px solid red
}
```

Comment: Why are you selecting `.a` at all?

Comment: i'm selecting a and the second child of a, both applying the style. Isn't @MoJS using the style?

Comment: No the OP only wants to style `.b`, not `.a`.

Answer (score -1):

What about this:

```
.a .b:first-child {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: That will also select the second `b`, since it's a descendant of `a` and a `first-child`.

Answer (score -1):

using `:first-child` will style every first-child  that has that class

for your example

```
.b:first-child
```

To restrict which first child should be used you will have to add other selectors to it.