# CSS nested rules, unexpected behaviour for overriding rules

Tags: html, css, web

I am experiencing a strange behaviour, but it is probably as it should be, however it is unexpected and undesired.

**The sample HTML:**

```
<div class='rtl'>

    <div class='ltr'>

        <div class='floatleft'>
            A 
        </div>        
        <div class='floatleft'>
            B
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

**and the CSS:**

```
.ltr .floatleft {  
    float:left;
}

.rtl .floatleft {  
    float:right;
}
```

The output however is floated right because it is the rule that is specified last in the css file: **.rtl .floatleft { float: right }**

However, sine the class 'ltr' is specified on a nested element, my hope or desire was for that rule to take precedence, so that you can always override whatever the ancestors has applied.

But this is not working though. Is there a way that I am unable to see here?

HERE IS ANOTHER QUESTION SIMILAR TO THIS ONE:

[CSS select next match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528801/css-select-next-match)

Answer (score 1):

It's just the order that your styles are written in this case.

`.ltr .floatleft` and `.rtl .floatleft` both equal true. So whichever one is the final rule in the CSS file is going to take precedence.

You need to add more specificity to whichever rule you actually want to take place.

Here's an example of how your styles can be different based on what order you've put them in:

[JSFiddle with orders swapped and then direct descendant examples.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/a773K/3/)

Comment: Yeah, I understand this. However, I believe people have asked for this before. 

If a content is provided or developed by a user, on which you already have specified the rule globally, it cannot be overriden. 

It has to do with the special use case of rtl languages ... float:left should become float:right ... it is defined on the root html tag first .. and then any supplied content can itself specify how its children should float ... now it is coming from GOD and no one can change it..

CSS should mature on this area

Comment: CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. The rules "cascade". All it is looking for is if a rule is either true or false. In this situation you have two true statements, so whichever rule comes last would have priority.

Comment: It is annoying that who ever is coding the little nested piece of code cannot change the behaviour of inherited css. Period. It is flawed by CSS and especially in the modular component building times on the WEB.

Comment: You can use a direct descendant selector: .rtl > .floatleft gives you the exact solution you want. Because it carries higher rule weight then .rtl .floatleft

Answer (score 0):

Float Left Needs to be it's own class.

```
.ltr {  
    float:left;
}
.floatleft{
    float:left;
}

.rtl{  
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnM53/1/

This way container div ltr will float left.  Container div rtl will float right as desired, but the div contents of ltr will float left within that div.  This is because you are no longer giving conflicting css information.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this as this lacks support in CSS is to add redundant and nested rules, ie:

```
.ltr .floatleft {  
    float:left;
}

.rtl .floatleft {  
    float:right;
}

.rtl .floatleft .ltr .floatleft {
    float:left;
}

.rtl .floatleft .ltr .floatleft .rtl .floatleft {
    float:right;
}

.rtl .floatleft .ltr .floatleft .rtl .floatleft .ltr .floatleft {
    float:left;
}

.rtl .floatleft .ltr .floatleft .rtl .floatleft .ltr .floatleft .rtl .floatleft {
    float:right;
}
```

And so on ... the same has to be done with the beginning of .ltr as for .rtl ... add as many as you want .. only way to get this behaviour unfortunately ...

**Or in less: **

```
.ltr(){
        direction: ltr;

        &.fl, .fl {
                float:left;
        }

        &.fr, .fr {
                float:right;
        }
}

.rtl(){
        direction: rtl;

        &.fl, .fl {
                float:right;
        }

        &.fr, .fr {
                float:left;
        }
}

[dir=ltr] {
        .ltr();
        [dir=rtl] {
                .rtl();
                [dir=ltr] {
                        .ltr();
                        [dir=rtl] {
                                .rtl();
                                [dir=ltr] {
                                        .ltr();
                                        [dir=rtl] {
                                                .rtl();
                                                [dir=ltr] {
                                                        .ltr();
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}

[dir=rtl] {
        .rtl();
        [dir=ltr] {
                .ltr();
                [dir=rtl] {
                        .rtl();
                        [dir=ltr] {
                                .ltr();
                                [dir=rtl] {
                                        .rtl();
                                        [dir=ltr] {
                                                .ltr();
                                                [dir=rtl] {
                                                        .rtl();
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what about `!important`?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E4Me/)

```
.ltr .floatleft {  
    float:left !important;
}

.rtl .floatleft {  
    float:right;
}
```

updated to work both ways:

http://jsfiddle.net/3E4Me/2/

Comment: It has to work both ways, if you put `.ltr` first, then `.rtl`, your solution doesn't work.

Comment: it is as mbillard is saying ... your solution will only work on this case and not the other way around, and not with more depths of nested elements.